# Navlink not working with html-react-parser - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, html-react-parser

I am new to react js, so kindly pardon my lack of knowledge on the subject here.
I did try googling and checking the "html-react-parser" page for any hints pertaining on the usage with navlink, but no luck there.

I have a simple react js application, wherein I am calling ajax via fetch from one of the component

```
getDataFromApi = () => {
Promise.all([
    fetch("http://localhost/sample/superadmin/callA.json").then((response) => response.json())
])
.then(([sidemenu]) => {
    this.setState({ sidemenu: sidemenu });
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
};

componentDidMount() {
    this.getDataFromApi();
}
```

And grabbing the output of fetch and using it construct a variable with HTML string

```
var sidemenu = "";
const sidemenuJSON = this.state.sidemenu;
Object.keys(sidemenuJSON).forEach(function(key, val) {
    if(key == "Dashboard") {
        sidemenu += "<li className='nav-item d-flex align-items-center'><NavLink className='nav-link fs-7 py-sm-2 "+key.toLowerCase()+"-navitem fc-light' to='/' ><span>"+key+"</span></NavLink></li>";
    }
    else {
        sidemenu += "<li className='nav-item d-flex align-items-center'><NavLink className='nav-link fs-7 py-sm-2 "+key.toLowerCase()+"-navitem fc-light' to='/"+key.toLowerCase()+"' ><span>"+key+"</span></NavLink></li>";
    }
});
```

and then rendering the HTML by passing it to html-react-parser parse function

```
{parse(sidemenu)}
```

The looks and feel seems to be fine at first glance, but the navlink is broken as it is not clickable anymore. Any idea on this?

Comment: React component <NavLink> will not work in the  HTML string, you should use them in React ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The correct way to use `React`.js

```
function SideMenusList(props) {
  const sidemenuJSON = props.sidemenu;
  // use NavLink as a component ✅
  const sideMenus = Object.keys(sidemenuJSON).map((key, index) => {
    if(key === "Dashboard") {
      return (
        <li className='nav-item d-flex align-items-center' key={key.toString() + index}>
          <NavLink className={'nav-link fs-7 py-sm-2' + key.toLowerCase() + '-navitem fc-light'} to='/' >
            <span>{key}</span>
          </NavLink>
        </li>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <li className='nav-item d-flex align-items-center'>
          <NavLink className={'nav-link fs-7 py-sm-2' + key.toLowerCase() + '-navitem fc-light'} to={'/' + key.toLowerCase()} >
            <span>{key}</span>
          </NavLink>
        </li>
      )
    }
  });
  return (
    <ul>{sideMenus}</ul>
  );
}
```

### tips

> You can learn more from the official docs.

https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists